# Default IValueConverter

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a simple `IValueConverter` which just uses a `TypeConverter` to do the conversions. However there are some cases where the `TypeConverter` provided will fail.

I would like to fall back to whatever WPF would have used if the the `Binding` was not provided with a converter. Using reflector I have determined that there is a `DefaultValueConverter` however it is internal to `MS.Internal.Data`.

Is there a simple way I can get my hands on a `DefaultValueConverter` or something that does the same thing?

Comment: I would just create a 'duplicate' MyDefaulValueConverter in my project and move on.

Comment: Amby makes a good suggestion, although I'm not sure what the license is on copying their code.  If it turns out you're allowed to, you could use http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx to extract the source code.

Comment: Their code, I just saw it now, is a little too complicated too copy, I would not suggest that! Try to fix instead the errors.

Comment: @Amby that was my first thought, however it relies on a number of other internal classes. Of course I can copy those, but they again use other internal classes, I haven't looked how far it goes, but its enough to make me look for other solutions.

Comment: A lot far, believe me, a lot far. Did you try with the old TypeConverter?

Comment: I have (that's what's causing the issue in fact ;)) Using it gives me an exception, where WPF binding works.

Comment: In reality I see that WPF uses TypeConverter internally to do most of the job, the difference is however how it get the typeconverter. Still studying why!

Comment: Did you try the XamlValueConverter? It is public. If you give us more details about the exception and what is source and target that gives you error I guess we can help more. Guess the problem should be solved in a more specific way.

Comment: Just slap reflections on it, write a comment `//Todo: Remove this hack when MS provides a way to access the default value converter properly`, and call it done.  :)

Comment: Yes :) suggested that as a very bad dirty hack, lol. And yes, I agree, nothing is pure and sometime we are forced to do dirty hacks, but spending some time to see if there is another road is good too.

Comment: @SalvatorePreviti: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/big-picture.html#faq-6.16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked a bit around with .NET reflector and it seems there is not an official way to get the default value converter.

What you need to be precise is to call the method

```
internal IValueConverter GetDefaultValueConverter(Type sourceType, Type targetType, bool targetToSource);
```

in class `MS.Internal.Data.DataBindEngine`.

You would get the current DataBindEngine for running thread with the static internal property

```
 internal static DataBindEngine CurrentDataBindEngine
```

Always in DataBindEngine class.

The problem is that the class is internal!

I looked also around to see if there is something public that uses that method but in reality that method and the default value converter classes (there is more than one!) are used only inside the internal databinding classes, so, no way out, sorry.

You could use reflection to access the internal members, but it would be a very bad dirty hack!
To do that, access to the static property DataBindEngine.CurrentDataBindEngine, then, access to the method GetDefaultValueConverter, always with reflection.
Wrap in a static function with the attribute [Obsolete] :)

Probably a cleaner way is to just use a default hand-written conversion.

You can just try understand why it gives you error or write a code that can handle the special cases. Their code is quite complicated and interlinked, I would not suggest to copy their code.

Sometime WPF makes me angry, a lot of things related to databinding are hidden, internal or not enough generic, and this is a really bad design choice that I don't understand.

The old TypeConverter sometime is enough. It depends on what you have to do.

```
public static object MyConvert(object value, Type t)
{
    TypeConverter tc = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(t);
    return tc.ConvertFrom(value);
}
```

You can also try the static method `Convert.ChangeType` that works with `IConvertible`.

I guess the problem is not in converting your object but converting it into a value used by a dependency property (or viceversa).
For this purpose there is the public class `XamlValueConverter`, used also internally by default value converters.
This is going to be complicated however, so ... not a real simple solution to your problem.

As Merlyn keep saying, I'm starting to believe that reflection may be a more suitable way.

Comment: Less to test and support.  And it doesn't paint them into a corner in case they decide to go with a different solution later.  If it turns out people need it after release, it is a simple one line change, a ton of design and testing (tho they might be able to leverage tests that already validate the default conversion code indirectly), and voila - done.

Comment: Yes quite probable answer indeed, but it makes still angry :) hope things will change a little with the next releases. Indeed databinding implementation is quite complicated. Hope also that in the next releases they make it more performant using less reflection and more Reflection.Emit :)

Comment: You call it evil and dirty, but if it is going to give the least surprising behavior I'd say that's what should be done.  It is highly unlikely that it would be removed or changed for the worse *without providing a similar publicly accessible functionality*.  So you can take advantage of the relatively slow momentum of the .Net Framework's progress, and assume they probably won't remove it in a hotfix or service release. If you slap a comment on it, you're placing the bread crumb trail to easily fix any bugs that occur, when they occur.

Comment: I said dirty but not evil to be precise. There are things more evil than this. Is just dirty, with the risk of being unsupported in the next releases.

Comment: Alas I am using 3.5, so no Xaml namespace for me.

Comment: Doh! Reflection... at least you are sure that it will work also in version 4.0 of the framework.

Comment: I have gone with the reflection method in the end. I believe that by using the strong name of the asm, the implementation shouldn't ever change under my feet (unless its not installed at all).

Answer (score 0):

As DefaultValueConverter is internal to MS.Internal.Data the best is to create your own version of default value converter